# In React how do I update the value of a input field that is of type="number"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have a React v16 app that has the following field

```
<input type="number" onChange={setQty} value={1} />
```

Then inside my `matchDispatchToProps` method I have this function:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        createItem(e) {
            ...
            setQty(e) {
                const qty = parseInt(e.target.value);
                // Max qty is 10
                if (qty < 10) {
                    ownProps.qty = qty;
                }
            }
            ...
```

Yet when I press the up and down arrows in the input box the value that is displayed is not updated, e.target.value is incrementing but won't go higher than 2, I guess this is because the input boxes value is still set to 1?

Comment: exactly, `value={1}` means the value will *always* be 1 as far the DOM is concerned, no matter what React says! It's not clear to me how best to fix because I'm not sure what your `mapDispatchToProps` is doing - but mutating `ownProps` as you are here is definitely not something you should do. It should update the Redux store (via the `dispatch` function argument to dispatch an action), then you can have a `mapStateToProps` that computes new props from the store.

Comment: thanks, I'll look at refactoring away from using props like this, in the end I learned that because I added a `value` field I was telling React to use the input field as a controlled input. I changed the property to `defaultValue` which prevents this from happening and allows me to have a default value on the form

Comment: no, that's the wrong way to go about it. You're right (usually) to make it a "controlled component" by providing the `value`, but the value (lol) of that prop shouldn't be a hard-coded number, it should be set to something in props or state (most likely props if you're using Redux) that will be updated as the user changes the value. (This is whay your `setQty` presumably does - the usual pattern with Redux is that that onChange handler will dispatch the value to the store, then in `mapStateToProps` you'll fetch that value into a prop which you then provide as the `value`.)